# POST request does not work

Tags: php, http, post, httprequest, fastcgi

I want to create a POST request to a website. For this I record the POST request with an addon for FireFox. I got this output:

```
https://XXXXXXXXXX/anmeldung.fcgi

POST /cgi/anmeldung.fcgi HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://YYYYYYYYYY/index.html
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 12
    name=cilenco

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2013 21:15:08 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.31
```

Now I want to recreate the POST Request with the [Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-rest-client/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb) for Google Chrome. I set the URL to the first line and the data to `name=cilenco` but it does not work. I get a wrong response. Do you have any ideas why or do I have to use more information from above?

The response should look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body class="anmeldung">
        <from>...</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I get a wrong response.` -- what's the response?

Comment: I'm forwarded to an other website

Comment: You're forwarded to another site because of `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://hsp-ms.uni-muenster.de/">` - what's wrong with that ? what result were you expecting ?

Comment: If the response contains a meta-refresh, you have to implement that redirection in your client application, it probably won't be done automatically by the REST client.

Comment: Okay maybe you understand my problem easier with the real URLs. The first: muenster.hochschulsport-nrw.de/angebote/aktueller_zeitraum/… if you click on the green button you are forwarded to an other website. There are many links with this green button but they all call the same URL with a POST request. I want to create a script which can send the id from the button to the script and get the new website as response.

Comment: I'm not sure how easy is it (if possible at all) since they use `Proxy-Authorization`

Answer (score 0):

The response that I receive looks fine, maybe you forgot something ?

[image]

Comment: No sry that is the forward to the other website. It should be an whole other site with a new formular

Comment: @Cilenco I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: I added my post above

Comment: Okay maybe you understand my problem easier with the real URLs. The first: http://muenster.hochschulsport-nrw.de/angebote/aktueller_zeitraum/_Korfball.html if you click on the green button you are forwarded to an other website. There are many links with this green button but they all call the same URL with a POST request. I want to create a script which can send the id from the button to the script and get the new website as response.